# Python Timestamp Dataframe Only Number/Decimal Filtering

Tags: python, dataframe, filter, timestamp

I have a dataframe

```
df['Timestamp']
153917800000
```

Applying .iso8601 returns as an object in the format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f I presume.

```
df['Timestamp']
2018-10-10T12:52:00.000Z
```

I would like to filter/remove/replace the dashes "-", and ":", and Timezones: "Z" to ""

Desired Output:

```
    df['Timestamp']
    20181010125200000
    dtype:float
```

Desired Application:
Manual function that requires float input

Attempts

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(float)


df['Timestamp'] = (df['Timestamp'].filter(_.isdigit()))
```

Comment: `print(pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f'))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df =  pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': ["2018-10-10T12:52:00.000Z"]})
print(pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f'))
```

**Output:**

```
0    20181010125200000000
Name: Timestamp, dtype: object
```